# silverlight treeview not loading subitems

Tags: c#, silverlight, treeview

I'm interested in finding out why this isn't working:

I have a treeview with some hierarchicaldatatemplates looking like this:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>     
            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="nodeEntry">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="rootEntry" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource nodeEntry}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>

    <sdk:TreeView Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource rootEntry}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=subjectDomainDataSource, Path=Data}" 
    Name="rootTreeView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"/>
```

The data is passed to the treeview from a domainservice using this method:

```
public IEnumerable<Subject> GetSubjectList(Guid userid)
    {
        DataLoadOptions loadopts = new DataLoadOptions();
        loadopts.LoadWith<Root>(s => s.Nodes);
        this.DataContext.LoadOptions = loadopts;
        return this.DataContext.Roots;
    }
```

why then are only the root nodes shown in the treeview as if it only loaded a flat list, and not a hierarchy where the root Loads the NodesCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my data. I had to add [include] in the domainservice matadata